# npm won't install the specified version of hardhat

Tags: node.js, npm, hardhat

I am trying to install hardhat and make it works. When I try `npm install --save-dev hardhat` and then check the installed version in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "hardhat": "^0.0.7"
}
```

But I am trying to install the latest version. Last time I checked, the latest version is `2.8.3`.  So I tried to install it with `npm install --save-dev hardhat@2.8.3`. But It still gives me the same version of `0.0.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the version of the package in your `package.json` itself.
from :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "hardhat": "^0.0.7"
}
```

to :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "hardhat": "^2.8.3"
}
```

and run `npm install` to install the the specified version.
I just tried to reproduce the same way you tried... but it worked for me.. Please try with the above method and pls let me know your feedback in the comments.
Thank you